# I combined 2 .csv files with 5 rows each and converted it into a df in Databricks Comm edition .But one column is having all null values in the df

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, databricks

```
+----------+---------+-------------+----------+-------+--------+-------+------+------------+------+
|Invoice ID|     City|Customer type|Unit price| Tax 5%|   Total|Payment|  cogs|gross income|Rating|
+----------+---------+-------------+----------+-------+--------+-------+------+------------+------+
| 750678428|   Yangon|       Member|     74.69|26.1415|548.9715|   null|522.83|     26.1415|   9.1|
| 226313081|Naypyitaw|       Normal|     15.28|   3.82|   80.22|   null|  76.4|        3.82|   9.6|
| 631413108|   Yangon|       Normal|     46.33|16.2155|340.5255|   null|324.31|     16.2155|   7.4|
| 123191176|   Yangon|       Member|     58.22| 23.288| 489.048|   null|465.76|      23.288|   8.4|
| 373737910|   Yangon|       Normal|     86.31|30.2085|634.3785|   null|604.17|     30.2085|   5.3|
| 750678428|   Yangon|       Member|     74.69|26.1415|548.9715|   null|522.83|     26.1415|   9.1|
| 226313081|Naypyitaw|       Normal|     15.28|   3.82|   80.22|   null|  76.4|        3.82|   9.6|
| 631413108|   Yangon|       Normal|     46.33|16.2155|340.5255|   null|324.31|     16.2155|   7.4|
| 123191176|   Yangon|       Member|     58.22| 23.288| 489.048|   null|465.76|      23.288|   8.4|
| 373737910|   Yangon|       Normal|     86.31|30.2085|634.3785|   null|604.17|     30.2085|   5.3|
+----------+---------+-------------+----------+-------+--------+-------+------+------------+------+
```

The payment column is completely NULL; but  indeed there is data in the input CSV files. How do I rectify this ?

Comment: Please post both CSV files and the code used to combine them.

Comment: hi Azhar ..Here is a google deive folder link where you can find    the cv files ,the code in a text file and the snapshot of the output .Plz help..                  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10XYr4ubVEO1eCFXTcIFrkdaguvMqF-QH?usp=sharing

Comment: @DataScienceEnthusiast What happens if you wrap your text fields in quotes? Like in this example: https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/read-csv-corrupt-record.html